# Jquery Validate with Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, coffeescript

SO I can make the following code work in javascript

```
validateSearchForm:=>
    $(@el).find("#form").validate({
      rules:{
        startDateInputBox:{
          dateISO:true,
          endDateInputBox:{lessThan : "#licenseStart"}
        },
        endDateInputBox:{
          dateISO:true
        }
        searchPurposeBox:"required"


      }



      });

  $.validator.addMethod "lessThan",(value,element)-> 
    //do some stuff
  ,"some comment"
```

But the lessThan function keeps being undefined in coffee. Pretty sure this is some syntax error - can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will fix your problem, but try to define your objects without `{}`:

```
rules:
    startDateInputBox:
        dateISO: true,
        endDateInputBox:
             lessThan: "#licenseStart"
    endDateInputBox:
         dateISO: true
    searchPurposeBox: "required"
```

Comment: The braces are optional and *optional* doesn't mean *forbidden*.

Answer (score 0):

Your code structure is like this:

```
validateSearchForm: =>
    $(@el).find('#form').validate({ ... })
    $.validator.addMethod "lessThan", (value, element) -> 
        #...
    , "some comment"
```

so you're calling `$.validator.addMethod` *after* you try to validate the form. You should add all your extra validation methods *before* you try to use them and you should probably add them outside your methods that will be validating forms. Something more like this:

```
# Somewhere in your global application set up...
$.validator.addMethod "lessThan", (value, element) -> 
    #...
, "some comment"

# And then elsewhere...
class Whatever
    #...
    validateSearchForm: =>
        $(@el).find('#form').validate({ ... })
```

You have to pay very close attention to your indentation in CoffeeScript, the indentation supplies half of your code's structure so it has to be right and it should be consistent.